# is there a faster way to sum picked pcs per hour

Tags: excel, vba

in this code i want to get per hour the sum of picked pcs 
so my excell sheet has many rows, i have alraedy a code  but it sums not fast enough, in column s is filled with longtimevalues  dd:mm:yyy & hh:mm:ss in column p is filled with the pcs that are picked on that time

aj2 till aj10 are hour value 5, 6, 7 and so on aj10 = 13
ak2 till ak10 are the pcs picked in that hour

same is 
al2 till al10 are hour value 14, 15, 16 and so on al10 = 22
am2 till am10 are the pcs picked in that hour

also it has to sum and check hour pcs only the visible cells that has values in it

the code for the moment i have is this     solution vba or excell

i have vba written for the moment but like i said not fast enough it takes a long way to summ all of the code

```
Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()

If CheckBox6.Value = True Then

Dim lijnen As String
lijnen = "an15:an" & Range("s15").End(xlDown).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In Range(lijnen).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If cell.Value <> "" Then

                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj2").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak2").Value = Range("ak2").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj3").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak3").Value = Range("ak3").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj4").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak4").Value = Range("ak4").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj5").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak5").Value = Range("ak5").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj6").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak6").Value = Range("ak6").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj7").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak7").Value = Range("ak7").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj8").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak8").Value = Range("ak8").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj9").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak9").Value = Range("ak9").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj10").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak10").Value = Range("ak10").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al2").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am2").Value = Range("am2").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al3").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am3").Value = Range("am3").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al4").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am4").Value = Range("am4").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al5").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am5").Value = Range("am5").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al6").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am6").Value = Range("am6").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al7").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am7").Value = Range("am7").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al8").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am8").Value = Range("am8").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value
                    Else
                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al9").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am9").Value = Range("am9").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value


                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    End If
                    Next cell
              End If
              Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You should use `ElseIf` rather than so many single `If` statements. It may not speed up your code much, but it'll look more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off Excel Calculations typically improves performance. The following code includes that along with cleaned up `If` statements.

```
If CheckBox6.Value = True Then

Dim lijnen As String
lijnen = "an15:an" & Range("s15").End(xlDown).Row

Dim calc As XlCalculation: calc = Application.Calculation 'captures your current setting

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each cell In Range(lijnen).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If cell.Value <> "" Then

                    If Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj2").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak2").Value = Range("ak2").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj3").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak3").Value = Range("ak3").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj4").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak4").Value = Range("ak4").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj5").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak5").Value = Range("ak5").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj6").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak6").Value = Range("ak6").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj7").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak7").Value = Range("ak7").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj8").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak8").Value = Range("ak8").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj9").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak9").Value = Range("ak9").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("aj10").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("ak10").Value = Range("ak10").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al2").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am2").Value = Range("am2").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al3").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am3").Value = Range("am3").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al4").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am4").Value = Range("am4").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al5").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am5").Value = Range("am5").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al6").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am6").Value = Range("am6").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al7").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am7").Value = Range("am7").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al8").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am8").Value = Range("am8").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    ElseIf Format(cell.Value, "hh") = Format(Range("al9").Value, "hh") Then
                    Range("am9").Value = Range("am9").Value + Range("p" & cell.Row).Value

                    End If
        End If
Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = calc 'resets this back to whatever it previously was

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help with the speed issue. I noticed that you use cell.value a lot and this eliminates that.  It also cleans up your code a bit.  However, it does not do any error checking if the cell is blank.

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()

        Dim strValue As String
        Dim lngRow As Long
        Dim lngPValue As Long
        Dim strPValue As String


        If CheckBox6.Value = True Then

            Dim lijnen As String
            lijnen = "an15:an" & Range("s15").End(xlDown).Row

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            For Each cell In Range(lijnen).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                strValue = Trim(cell.value)

                If strValue <> "" Then
                    strValue = Format(cell.Value, "hh")

                    lngRow = cell.Row
                    strPValue = Trim(Range("p" & lngRow).Value)
                    lngPValue = CLng(strPValue)

                    If strValue = Format(Range("aj2").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("ak2").Value = Range("ak2").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("aj3").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("ak3").Value = Range("ak3").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("aj4").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("ak4").Value = Range("ak4").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("aj5").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("ak5").Value = Range("ak5").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("aj6").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("ak6").Value = Range("ak6").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("aj7").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("ak7").Value = Range("ak7").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("aj8").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("ak8").Value = Range("ak8").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("aj9").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("ak9").Value = Range("ak9").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("aj10").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("ak10").Value = Range("ak10").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("al2").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("am2").Value = Range("am2").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("al3").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("am3").Value = Range("am3").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("al4").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("am4").Value = Range("am4").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("al5").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("am5").Value = Range("am5").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("al6").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("am6").Value = Range("am6").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("al7").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("am7").Value = Range("am7").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("al8").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("am8").Value = Range("am8").Value + lngPValue
                    ElseIf strValue = Format(Range("al9").Value, "hh") Then
                        Range("am9").Value = Range("am9").Value + lngPValue
                    End If
                End If
            Next cell
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: i will try the code, also did the one above great that you want to respond me thx

Comment: you can also insert what @PGCodeRider said for his code into what I put. It will help speed up the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to avoid looping but loop through arrays if you have to loop. Your SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) presents a problem as there may be non-contiguous Areas within the range but these can be dealt with.

You've written `If ElseIf ElseIf ElseIf ... End If` comparisons. I've changed this to a worksheet's Match comparison.

Range.Value2 (without regional date/time or currency information) is marginally faster than Range.Value. Numerical collection and comparison is faster than string collection and comparison.

This appears to be written as a private sub within a worksheet's private code sheet so explicitly defining the parent worksheet reference should be unnecessary.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()

    If CheckBox6.Value Then 'CheckBox6 is either True of False; you don't have to compare it to True

        Dim i As Long, a As Long, lr As Long, rngP As Range, rngAN As Range
        Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, m As Variant

        'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'build the hours tables
        ReDim hrs(1 To 18) As Variant
        ReDim pAK(1 To 9) As Variant
        ReDim pAm(1 To 9) As Variant
        For i = 2 To 10
            hrs(i - 1) = Hour(Cells(i, "AJ").Value2)
            hrs(i + 8) = Hour(Cells(i, "AL").Value2)
        Next i

        'collect the filtered values from columns P and AN
        lr = Cells(15, "AN").End(xlDown).Row
        Set rngP = Range(Cells(15, "P"), Cells(lr, "P")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Set rngAN = Range(Cells(15, "AN"), Cells(lr, "AN")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        'loop through the areas of SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        For a = 1 To rngAN.Areas.Count
            'collect the Area's values
            arr1 = rngAN.Areas(a).Cells.Value2
            arr2 = rngP.Areas(a).Cells.Value2

            'loop through the array
            For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)

                'determine if Hour is in AJ2:AJ10 or AL2AL10
                m = Application.Match(Hour(arr1(i, 1)), hrs, 0)
                If Not IsError(m) Then
                    If m < 10 Then
                        pAK(m) = pAK(m) + arr2(i, 1)
                    Else
                        pAm(m - 9) = pAm(m - 9) + arr2(i, 1)
                    End If
                End If

            Next i

        Next a

        'dump processed values back to worksheet
        Cells(2, "AK").Resize(UBound(pAK), 1) = Application.Transpose(pAK)
        Cells(2, "AM").Resize(UBound(pAm), 1) = Application.Transpose(pAm)

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If

End Sub
```